# Microphone not working properly during call (LG G2)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, microphone, lg-g2

I have an LG G2 (d802) with a rooted Lollipop rom installed. During any call the person I'm speaking with has difficulties hearing my voice due to stuttering and distorted sound. Sometimes they stop hearing me altogether and I found out that if I mute and unmute the microphone it starts working again for a very brief period of time. Before dispatching it to the repair shop, is there anything I can do to try and fix the problem? To rule out any (possible?) software bugs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give [Microphone Guard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.auradesign.microphoneguard) a try.

My Mobile was working only on Loud-speaker (software issue) and it helped me.

Comment: Could you please explain in which way it did help you? Were you able to fix the microphone issue? Looks like this app prevents eavesdropping, not what I need.